# Different CMFCColorButton behavior between 2 applications

Tags: c++, mfc, behavior

Using MFC in Visual Studio 2012

I want to use a CMFCColorButton in a dialog in my application.

I added the CMFCColorButton button to my dialog in the resource editor (test it, works OK); click on the button and the underlying CMFCColorPopupMenu is display and stay displayed until manually dismissed (choosing a color or clicking somewhere else).

When I build my application and try the button in the dialog, it works differently, when I click the button, the underlying CMFCColorPopupMenu is displayed and immediately dismissed. If I want to select a color, I need to keep the mouse button down.

I tried in a different application (default MFC application) and I get the desired behavior (click and the CMFCColorPopupMenu stay visible).

I am not certain what could trigger the behavior difference.

I try toggling the CMFCColorButton::m_bAutoSetFocus value of the button and there is no change of behavior. ( I am not certain what is the purpose of this variable, but that is another subject)

Any ideas? hints/tips?

Thanks, 
Max.

Comment: Are you handling mouse messages? Focus? Anything funny in them (like activating some specific window, for example)?

Comment: You should post the relevant code.

Comment: it is a simple CDialog... no handlers or message.